# How can I erase individual chrome pre-filled in entries?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, auto-form-fill

I am using Chrome on Mac OS X and when filling in web forms, such as an email address, it attempts to prefill in the email address based upon matching the characters typed thus far with the previously seen email addresses.

However, some email addresses I do not want to be remembered anymore, how can I erase individual entries without erasing all learned field values?  Is there a file that can be edited somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open up the Chrome Preferences and select Manage Autofill settings under Passwords and forms.  Edit the entries to remove the email addresses that should not be autofilled.